# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP still results 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table called "Date" (well actually its "Datum, which is Dutch for "Date"), which I want to automatically give a value whenever a record gets added. But it doesn't seem to work. Whatever I do it still fills in 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I've tried to alter the table with:

```
ALTER TABLE article CHANGE Datum
Datum TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() 
ON UPDATE NOW()
```

That didn't work so I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE article CHANGE Datum
Datum TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Which didn't work either. Insert query I used:

```
"INSERT INTO artikelen(Articleid, Title, Article, Date, Type, author) values ('', '$Title', '$Article', '', '$Type', '$author')")
```

Yes it uses PHP variables.

Comment: your 2nd alter query is fine. how you are inserting data, share one row insert statement.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I've added the query I use to insert data.

Comment: @BadAtPHP:- Its working for me...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/574d7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specif the date column if you have set it to default. Try like this(*Date column which is set to default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is removed*):

```
"INSERT INTO artikelen(Articleid, Title, Article,  Type, author) values ('', '$Title', '$Article', '$Type', '$author')")
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/574d7/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Its no fully clear what your doing. Your using a column 'Datum' in your table, while in the PHP you reference to 'Date'. Assuming  you mean the same, the definition below should work. *However*, if you add a empty value in your SQL statement for your date column (my case my_date), then the update will not fire. So make sure you **omit** the column in your INSERT/UPDATE statement.

Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `my_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```